# Two elementary questions about integration with respect to measures

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am a self-studying a book about fractal geometry in which some notions of measure theory are reviewed. As one who had zero background in measure theory, I am puzzled about some aspects of what I read. Accordingly, can one please shed some light on the following questions?

1- Given a non-negative simple function $f:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (with finitely many values $a_{1}, \cdots, a_{k}$) and a measure $\mu$, one may define the following integral:

$$\int f \text{d}\mu = \sum_{i=1}^{k}a_{i}\mu\{x:f(x)=a_{i}\}.$$

If $f$ is surjective, one may simply take $\mu$ as the Lebesgue measure since we have multiple $a_{i}$ satisfying $f(x) = a_{i}$. But what if $f$ is bijective, according to which the solution to $f(x) = a_{i}$ is just a singleton? In this case, one cannot employ Lebesgue measure because we have single numbers not intervals (If a define an interval [a,a] for value a, then the Lebesgue measure of that interval trivially vanishes, per definition). So, what can the measure be for the integration of a bijective function with respect to that measure?

2- My text says

> The integral of more general functions is defined using approximation
> by simple functions. if $f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a non-negative
> function, we define its integral as
>
> $$\int f \text{d}\mu = \text{sup}\Bigg\{\int g \text{d}\mu: g \text{
>  is simple, }0\le g\le f\Bigg\}.$$

I suppose that "more general functions" does not refer to those including infinite values because that violates the Borel assumption. Thus, what are those "more general functions", and how to integrate infinite-value functions with respect to a measure?

Comment: Take another look at the definition of a simple function: they can take only finitely many distinct values, and thus will never be surjective or bijective (if the domain is infinite). Also note that the definition of $\int f\,d\mu$ starts with a given function $f$ and a given measure $\mu$; the measure isn't something that one chooses.

Comment: @GregMartin: Thanks. But I didn't understand your last sentence. Let's assume that one would like to define a measure for the integration of a known function $f$. So, the measure needs to be chosen, right?